# Как исправить ошибку bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('?

Tags: linux, bash, числа-фибоначчи

**bash: 4.4.12(1)-release**

Имеется команда

```
! : "`/???/???/???${#?}???<<<_.`";_____=${_::-~$?} ____='__+=___,___=__-___,__<_[$($_____<<<$___>&$[-~${##}])]||____' ((__=-~$?,____))|&$_____
```

которая должна вывести числа Фибоначчи.

P.S.: Вообще не представляю, как это может работать, а понять ошибку в данном случае нельзя. Команда не моя.

---

Есть еще одна команда

```
: "`/???/???/???${#?}???<<<]`";/???/${_::${#?}}??${_:${#?}:${#?}}
```

которая печатает дату. И здесь всё работает нормально, а вот с Фибоначчи ошибочку получаю.

Comment: Мне кажется, лучше обратиться к автору этой команды

Comment: @0xdb, `set -x`, извиняюсь, опечатался. `set -x`, это режим отладки, затем запуск команды, будет выведено более подробное сообщение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первую команду разбирать нет желания, разберу вторую, и если хотите, по тому же принципу разбирайте первую, благо идея очень незатейливая.

Подставляем первый `${#?}`, предполагается что там будет 1, потому, что это длина кода возврата предыдущей команды. Обычно это код 0 (если не произошло обшики), соответственно его длина 1:

```bsh
: "`/???/???/???1???<<<]`";/???/${_::${#?}}??${_:${#?}:${#?}}
```

по маске `/???/???/???1???`, после поиска по диску, найдется команда `/usr/bin/sha1sum`, по крайней мере на это рассчитывает скрипт:

```bsh
: "`/usr/bin/sha1sum<<<]`";/???/${_::${#?}}??${_:${#?}:${#?}}
```

`/usr/bin/sha1sum<<<]` примерно соответсвует `echo "]" | /usr/bin/sha1sum`. Подставляем результат:

```bsh
: "de603c91038f329cce1cca8a30ea161b2271e2f6 -";/???/${_::${#?}}??${_:${#?}:${#?}}
```

команда `: "de603c91038f329cce1cca8a30ea161b2271e2f6 -"` не делает ничего полезного, но соответствующая строчка осядет в `$_`, а код ошибки `$?` станет равным 0

Поэтому вместо последующих `${#?}` подставятся единицы, правда в моей (более ранней) версии `bash` такая подстановка срабатывает неправильно:

```bsh
/???/${_::1}??${_:1:1}
```

Далее подставляем подстроки переменной `$_`: `${_::1}` берет ее первый символ, т.е. `d`, а `${_:1:1}` - второй, т.е. `e`

```bsh
/???/d??e
```

по маске найдется `/bin/date`

Comment: SHA сумма является не командой, а аргументом команды `:`.

Comment: @0andriy, благодарю, исправил.

Comment: На случай, если кто-то хочет деталей по моему комментарию: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224910/2511795